# How to upgrade to windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade

Ive got windows 10 home edition that came pre installed on an HP laptop (2.5ghz i5, 8gb ram)

I want to upgrade to windows 10 pro so that i can use windows remote desktop.

Where can i buy an update file / disk to go from windows 10 home to windows 10 pro ? (ive search online but can only seem to find new versions of windows 10 pro rather than upgrade versions)

Also does windows 10 pro have any advanced system requirements over and above those of window 10 home ?

Comment: "Where can i buy an update file / disk to go from windows 10 home to windows 10 pro ?" You can't. You need to buy a Windows Pro licence. See [Upgrade Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro - Windows Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12384/windows-10-upgrading-home-to-pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can i buy an update file / disk to go from windows 10 home to windows 10 pro ?

As DavidPostill said, you need to by a Windows 10 Pro License. [Per this Microsoft Support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12384/windows-10-upgrading-home-to-pro), here are the upgrade steps:

1. Select the Start  button, then select Settings  > Update & security  > Activation.
2. Select Change product key, and then enter the 25-character Windows 10 Pro product key.
3. Select Next to start the upgrade to Windows 10 Pro.

> Also does windows 10 pro have any advanced system requirements over and above those of window 10 home ?

System requirements? No. The laptop specs you provided are more than enough.

System features? Yes. Take a look at [Microsoft's feature breakdown between Pro and Home here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compare).

> I want to upgrade to windows 10 pro so that i can use windows remote desktop.

Just to be clear, you will be able to USE Remote Desktop in Windows 10 Home to remote to another computer. You just cannot Remote Desktop TO the Windows 10 Home computer.

If this is your only feature gap, you may want to consider [using alternative remote access tools such as TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.us/), (which is free for personal use) to avoid purchasing a license and going through the upgrade process. A tool like this would also have the added benefit of being able to access the computer when being on a separate network.